# How to write query to get progressbar is present or not

Tags: android, calabash

I have written query check whether progressbar is present on view or not.
I issue following command but it does not works

```
query("progressbar class:'android.widget.ProgressBar'")
```

When I issue query("*") command it will returns as one of the element

```
[8] {
                      "id" => "progress",
                 "enabled" => true,
      "contentDescription" => nil,
                   "class" => "android.widget.ProgressBar",
                    "rect" => {
          "center_y" => 419.0,
          "center_x" => 194.0,
            "height" => 72,
                 "y" => 383,
             "width" => 72,
                 "x" => 158
      },
             "description" => "android.widget.ProgressBar@4138e948"
  },
```

Any body knows how to fetch progressbar element using query command?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Well better late then never - try something like

```
  def check_loading
   wait_for_elements_exist([query_progress_bar], :timeout => 22, :timeout_message => "No Progress Bar")
  end

  def query_progress_bar
   'android.widget.ProgressBar'
  end
```

If you are looking for a certain class, just query for the class name like

```
query('android.widget.ProgressBar')
```

you can add information like in your case

```
query('android.widget.ProgressBar id:"progress"')
```